# Update only ForeignKey field in Django form

Tags: python, django

I try to update a ForeignKey field of a model in django form. I want a user not to write his name into a input field as an author of the article that he wrote but his `id`must be saved in the field in `Article` model. In my html-form I display only a button with hidden input. But in my views.py I write that the form should take `user.id` and put it in the `'article_author'` field.

Unfortunately, I've got no updates into table. What am I doing wrong?

my model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_pub_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,verbose_name="Дата публикации")
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name="Заголовок", null=True)
    article_text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Текст", null=True)
    article_author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Автор', blank=True, null=True)
```

my views.py

```
def article_detail(request, article_id):
    user = request.user
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
    author_form = ArticleForm(request.POST or None, instance=article, initial={'article_author': user.id})
    if author_form.is_valid():
        author_form.save()
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

my forms.py

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('article_author',)
        widgets = {'article_author': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

and my template:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ author_form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="BIND" class="btn">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the following:

```
if author_form.is_valid():
    article = author_form.save(commit=False)
    article.article_author = user
    # article.article_author_id = user.id  #w ill work as well
    article.save()
else:
    return redirect('/')
```

or in the form instantiation:

```
initial={'article_author_id': user.id}
```